# Calculating Probability

Tags: function, loops, vector, probability, std-pair

So, I'm attempting to calculate the probability of a specific key within a vector of pairs. Each specific key within the vector has a specific weight, and in order to calculate the specific probability of that key, I have to add the weight of all the keys within the vector together, and then divide the specific by the total.

Here's what I have so far.

```
  double probability(KEY_T key) const
    {
        int MAX = 0;
        int TARGET = 0;
        int size = _valueToWeightMap.size();


        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
        {
            if (_valueToWeightMap[x].first == key)
            {
                TARGET = _valueToWeightMap[x].second;
            }
            MAX += _valueToWeightMap[x].second;
        }

        return (TARGET / MAX);
    }
```

And this is the main.

```
int main()
{
    DiscreteDistribution<std::string> dist1;

    dist1.add("Helmet", 1);
    dist1.add("Gloves", 5);
    dist1.add("cloud", 8);




    std::cout << dist1.probability("cloud") << std::endl;


    system("pause");
```

For some reason, I keep getting the result 0. What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: integer division. 4/5 = 0. Unrelated but if see a variable in UPPER case I expect it to be a constant...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using integers and dividing, it will automatically take just the part before the decimal (being an integer)

Change the datatype to float, that should fix it!